# Excel VBA to change border color - only visible borders

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel form whose borders are in black color. I would like to change it to other color. I tried the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

It changed the borders of all cells, including those cells which did not have borders, into red. This is not what I want. I want those borders in black to turn red and the invisible borders to stay invisible. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can loop through the  `UsedRange` like in the answer below.

Comment: @JvdV As a test, I tried ActiveSheet.Range("P27:X30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions).Select. It did not select anything. Any sample code would be welcome.

Comment: @joehua, excuses, thought you meant conditional formatting. Either way, I also added an interesting approuch to this matter that don't require looping all cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Mikku's input, I got the following code to work.

```
Sub change_border_color()

'change the color of existing borders
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

If cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 1 Then
    cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End If

If cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = 1 Then
    cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End If

If cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = 1 Then
    cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End If

If cell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = 1 Then
    cell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can shorten your code a little by `For i = xlEdgeLeft To xlEdgeRight`, as the four outer borders are defined by `xlEdgeLeft` = 7, `xlEdgeTop` = 8, `xlEdgeBottom` = 9, `xlEdgeRight` = 10.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way of doing things making use of [`FindFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.findformat) and [`ReplaceFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.replaceformat) properties.

```
Sub BordersReplace()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For X = xlEdgeLeft To xlEdgeRight
        With Application.FindFormat.Borders(X)
            .Color = 0
        End With
        With Application.ReplaceFormat.Borders(X)
            .Color = 255
        End With
        .Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", searchformat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
        Application.FindFormat.Clear
        Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
    Next X
End With

End Sub
```

Small loop involved to go through the appropriate [`XLBordersIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbordersindex) enumeration.

Note, not clearing `FindFormat` and `ReplaceFormat` will make Excel keep working with the first used format, hence why the `.Clear` is nesseccary.

I myself am a little bit puzzled on why it would't work on the cells with all edges on its borders applied. For that to work use `Application.FindFormat.Borders()`

Comment: smart use of looping :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, allthough it's interesting I'm puzzled on why it wouldn't change the borders of a cell with all edges.. any idea?

Comment: All non-defined and greyed-out borders in the search dialog unfortunately are AND-conditioned as "no border" by Excel, as you can try by a manual format search. So your loop will only find cells with 1 border and no cell with 2, 3 or 4 borders. +1 for a still interesting attempt.

Comment: @Asger, thanks for the explaination, this makes sense, but also for this case a not so usefull answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Sub chgBorderColor_On_AllSheets()

'change the color of existing borders on all sheets

```
Dim Current As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim Red As Integer, Green As Integer, Blue As Integer
Dim NewColor As Long
Dim i As Integer


Red = Application.InputBox("Input R component of RGB", "Line color definition", Type:=1)

Green = Application.InputBox("Input G component of RGB", "Line color definition", Type:=1)

Blue = Application.InputBox("Input B component of RGB", "Line color definition", Type:=1)
NewColor = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Current In Worksheets

For Each cell In Current.UsedRange
    
    For i = xlEdgeLeft To xlEdgeRight '7 to 10
    
        If cell.Borders(i).LineStyle = xlContinuous Or _
            cell.Borders(i).LineStyle = xlDouble Or _
            cell.Borders(i).LineStyle = xlDot Or _
            cell.Borders(i).LineStyle = xlDash Or _
            cell.Borders(i).LineStyle = xlDashDot Or _
            cell.Borders(i).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot Or _
            cell.Borders(i).LineStyle = xlSlantDashDot Then
        
            cell.Borders(i).Color = NewColor
            
        End If
    Next
Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

A Loop will work fine. Currently you are setting the complete Range and changing it's border, you only need to do that with cells having any Value.

This loop will colour the Border Red if cell currently have any border.

```
For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    If Not cel.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 0 Then

        cel.Borders.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If

Next
```

This loop will color the Borders where the cel have some Value.

```
For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    If Not cel.Value = "" Then
        cel.Borders.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I want. The first code converts the border of every cell into red. It's like selecting the range and set the borders to red. Every border in every cell turns red. I have cells that, say, only have top and bottom borders, no left or right borders. In that case, I want only the top and bottom borders to be red and left and right borders stay invisible. I think what I need is go into every cell's border and check each border. If it is black, or any other color, change it to red.